# Erro - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

```
03-20 10:35:20.250: I/Process(897): Sending signal. PID: 897 SIG: 9
03-20 10:35:25.870: E/SQLiteLog(914): (1) no such column: name
03-20 10:35:25.870: E/data(914): Error while searching contacts: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: name (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, lastname, phone FROM contact
03-20 10:35:25.880: D/AndroidRuntime(914): Shutting down VM
03-20 10:35:25.880: W/dalvikvm(914): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4aefb90)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914): Process: br.com.contactsmanager, PID: 914
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.contactsmanager/br.com.contactsmanager.ContactRegister}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at br.com.contactsmanager.ContactRepository.listContacts(ContactRepository.java:166)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at br.com.contactsmanager.ContactRegister.updateList(ContactRegister.java:39)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at br.com.contactsmanager.ContactRegister.onCreate(ContactRegister.java:34)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
03-20 10:35:25.890: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  ... 11 more
```

O LogCat está acusando um problema de NullPointerException, porém não consigo identificar. Ao meu ponto de vista, tá certinho. Sei que tem problema nas linhas 34 e 39 do ContactRegister que levam à condição if(moveToFirst()) no ContactRepository, mas não consigo entender qual o erro.

Seguem os códigos do ContactRepository e ContactRegister. Se houver necessidade de postar mais algum, me avisem nos comentários.

O projeto se trata de uma agenda de contatos sincronizada com a do Android, que servirá de base para um aplicativo a ser desenvolvido.

**ContactRepository.java**

```
package br.com.contactsmanager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.util.Log;
import br.com.contactsmanager.Contact.Contacts;

public class ContactRepository {

    private static final String CATEGORY = "data";

    private static final String DB_NAME = "android_data";

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "contact";

    protected SQLiteDatabase db;

    public ContactRepository(Context ctx) 
    {

        db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    }

    protected ContactRepository() 
    {

    }

    public long save(Contact contact) 
    {
        long id = contact.id1;

        if (id != 0) {
            update(contact);
        }
        else
        {

            id = insert(contact);
        }

        return id;
    }

    // Insere uma nova pessoa   
    public long insert(Contact contact)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Contacts.NAME, contact.name1);
        values.put(Contacts.LASTNAME, contact.name2);
        values.put(Contacts.PHONE, contact.phone1);

        long id = insert(values);
        return id;
    }

    // Insere uma nova pessoa
    public long insert(ContentValues values)
    {
        long id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, "", values);
        return id;
    }

    // Atualiza a pessoa no banco. O id da pessoa é utilizado.
    public int update(Contact contact) 
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Contacts.NAME, contact.name1);
        values.put(Contacts.LASTNAME, contact.name2);
        values.put(Contacts.PHONE, contact.phone1);

        String _id = String.valueOf(contact.id1);

        String where = Contacts._ID + "=?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] { _id };

        int count = update(values, where, whereArgs);

        return count;

    }

    // Atualiza a pessoa com os valores abaixo
    // A cláusula where é utilizada para identificar a pessoa a ser atualizado
    public int update(ContentValues values, String where, String[] whereArgs) 
    {
        int count = db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, where, whereArgs);
        Log.i(CATEGORY, "Updated [" + count + "] registers");
        return count;
    }

    // Deleta a pessoa com o id fornecido
    public int delete(long id) {
        String where = Contacts._ID + "=?";

        String _id = String.valueOf(id);
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] { _id };

        int count = delete(where, whereArgs);

        return count;
    }

    // Deleta a pessoa com os argumentos fornecidos
    public int delete(String where, String[] whereArgs) {
        int count = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, where, whereArgs);
        Log.i(CATEGORY, "Has deleted [" + count + "] registers");
        return count;
    }

    // Busca a pessoa pelo id
    public Contact searchContact(long id) 
    {
        // select * from pessoa where _id=?
        Cursor c = db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, Contact.columns, Contacts._ID + "=" + id, null, null, null, null, null);

        c.moveToFirst ();

        if (c.getCount() > 0) {

            // Posiciona no primeiro elemento do cursor
            //c.moveToFirst ();

            Contact contact = new Contact();

            // Lê os dados
            contact.id1 = c.getLong(0);
            contact.name1 = c.getString(1);
            contact.name2 = c.getString(2);
            contact.phone1 = c.getInt(3);

            return contact;
        }

        return null;
    }

    // Retorna um cursor com todas as pessoas
    public Cursor getCursor() 
    {
        try {
            // select * from pessoas
            return db.query(TABLE_NAME, Contact.columns, Contacts.NAME, null, null, null, null, null); 
        } 
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            Log.e(CATEGORY, "Error while searching contacts: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Retorna uma lista com todas as pessoas
    public List<Contact> listContacts() 
        {
        Cursor c = getCursor();

        List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

        if ( c.moveToFirst() )
        {

            // Recupera os índices das colunas
            int idxId = c.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID);
            int idxFirstName = c.getColumnIndex(Contacts.NAME);
            int idxLastName = c.getColumnIndex(Contacts.LASTNAME);
            int idxPhone = c.getColumnIndex(Contacts.PHONE);

            // Loop até o final
            do 
            {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contacts.add(contact);

                // recupera os atributos da pessoa
                contact.id1 = c.getLong(idxId);
                contact.name1 = c.getString(idxFirstName);
                contact.name2 = c.getString(idxLastName);
                contact.phone1 = c.getInt(idxPhone);

            } 
            while ( c.moveToNext() );
        }

        return contacts;
    }

    // Busca a pessoa pelo nome "select * from pessoa where nome=?"
    public Contact searchContactByName(String name1) {
        Contact contact = null;

        try {
            // Idem a: SELECT _id,nome,cpf,idade from pessoa where nome = ?
            Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, Contact.columns, Contacts.NAME + "='" + name1 + "'", null, null, null, null);

            // Se encontrou...
            if (c.moveToNext()) {

                contact = new Contact();

                // utiliza os métodos getLong(), getString(), getInt(), etc para recuperar os valores
                contact.id1 = c.getLong(0);
                contact.name1 = c.getString(1);
                contact.name2 = c.getString(2);
                contact.phone1 = c.getInt(3);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(CATEGORY, "Error while searching person by name: " + e.toString());
            return null;
        }

        return contact;
    }

    // Busca uma pessoa utilizando as configurações definidas no
    // SQLiteQueryBuilder
    // Utilizado pelo Content Provider de pessoa
    public Cursor query(SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
            String groupBy, String having, String orderBy) 
    {
        Cursor c = queryBuilder.query(this.db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
        return c;
    }

    // Fecha o banco
    public void close() 
    {
        // fecha o banco de dados
        if (db != null) 
        {
            db.close();
        }
    }

}

----------------------
```

**ContactRegister.java**

```
package br.com.contactsmanager;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import br.com.contactsmanager.Contact.Contacts;

public class ContactRegister extends ListActivity {
    protected static final int INSERT_EDIT = 1;
    protected static final int SEARCH = 2;

    public static ContactRepositoryScript repository;


    private List<Contact> contacts;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        repository = new ContactRepositoryScript(this);
        updateList();
    }

    protected void updateList() 
    {
        contacts = repository.listContacts();

        setListAdapter(new ContactListAdapter(this, contacts));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, INSERT_EDIT, 0, "Insert new").setIcon(R.drawable.newcontact);
        menu.add(0, SEARCH, 0, "Search").setIcon(R.drawable.search);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case INSERT_EDIT:

            startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, EditContact.class), INSERT_EDIT);
            break;
        case SEARCH:

            startActivity(new Intent(this, SearchContact.class));
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        editContact(position);
    }

    protected void editContact(int position) 
    {
        Contact contact = contacts.get(position);

        Intent it = new Intent(this, EditContact.class);

        it.putExtra(Contacts._ID, contact.id1);

        startActivityForResult(it, INSERT_EDIT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int code, int returnCode, Intent it) {
        super.onActivityResult(code, returnCode, it);

        if (returnCode == RESULT_OK) 
        {
            updateList();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

        repository.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Certifique-se de que está a colocar o código todo. Eu pelo menos não consegui encontrar, nem com a ajuda do Ctrl+F o método listContacts() da classe ContactRepositoryScript. Sendo aí o erro actual faria sentido listar o código desse método. Uma vez que esteja disponível então darei uma vista de olhos e tentarei encontrar a fonte do NullPointerException.

Comment: Poderia postar o código das linhas 34 e 39 do ContactRegister separado pra mim olhar certinho?

Comment: As linhas por si só não fazem sentido se vistas sozinhas. Porém, aqui estão:  
34- updateList();
39- contacts = repository.listContacts();

Comment: ah, você comentou elas dizendo `//erro aqui`, agora que eu vi , rs.

Comment: Comentei sim! :D

Comment: Leo, o seu erro está no `ContactRepository.java` porém não sei te dizer onde exatamente, só sei te dizer que está na função `listContacts()`. Sugiro a você debugar a função `listContacts()` e ver em que linha que vai dar erro, aí quem sabe eu possa te ajudar.

Comment: Paulo, debuguei o listContacts, mas o erro continua o mesmo. Aponta as consequências, e ao chegar no possível ponto inicial, me deparo com a origem do listContacts ou o moveToFirst do cursor.

Comment: O engraçado é que até tentei tirar a declaração da ArrayList comentando-a, mas ainda assim o erro persiste, então acredito que seja independente dessa linha. Talvez um erro de posicionamento de cursor?

Comment: Verifique se seu cursor segue o seguinte padrão: `while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) cursor.moveToFirst(); //realiza operação... e depois: cursor.moveToNext();` e depois que terminar `cursor.close()`

Comment: Não tem o "close". Uma coisa que reparei é que a sintaxe moveToFirst é utilizada pela segunda vez em um condição if. Observe no ContactRepository. A primeira declaração está dentro de um getCount no método SearchContacts. Será que o dispositivo está esperando por um valor no if, que só pode ser obtido caso um contato seja pesquisado?

Comment: Peço desculpas caso fale alguma bobeira. Estou trabalhando com java há dois meses, mas antes disso nunca tive nenhum contato com a linguagem de programação orientada a objeto. Apenas C, C++ e por blocos.

Comment: Editei o post e aguardo aprovação do pessoal que o suspendeu.

Comment: @LeoS: :) vamos lá, primeiro você tinha postado uma pergunta/erro, que foi resolvida abaixo. Depois disto você colocou em um comentário que ia editar o código para a pessoa poder te ajudar mais. Isto seria outra pergunta. 2o: o pessoal não gosta mesmo de perguntas longas e códigos grandes. O objetivo é tirar dúvidas, não rever o código inteiro da pessoa buscando erros. Até porque não vamos importar o seu projeto inteiro para poder setar breakpoints e rodar passo-a-passo, vendo o conteúdo de cada variável conforme ele é executado.

Comment: @LeoS: 3o: o log de erro começa com um erro de SQL de não achar a coluna "name". Não achei no seu código de onde vem o Contact, imagino que seja algum dos imports. Mas me chamou a atenção também o método "public Contact searchContactByName(String name1)", por que dentro dele tem um Contact contact =null, e dentro do if ele vira um contact =new Contact(). Ou seja, ele só existe dentro do if, não? E fora do if volta a ser um contact=null... vc, debugando, poderia setar um ponto aí e ver o conteúdo dele dentro e fora do IF. Eu não, pq não vou importar seu projeto todo.

Comment: Pode deixar, vou fazer isso. Também vou evitar mais conteúdo "desnecessário" a vocês nas perguntas.

Comment: @leo.saldanha Como a pergunta original obteve a resposta (aparentemente), vou remover a supensão. Marque a resposta que te ajudou como correta e, caso tenha novas dúvidas, **faça outra pergunta**. Não há problema algum em perguntar várias vezes. É a melhor alternativa para garantir que o site permaneça organizado, e mais pessoas possam se beneficiar das respostas.

Answer (score 2):

Como você pode ver nesta linha de erro:

```
03-20 10:03:32.510: E/AndroidRuntime(940): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "9851": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: insert into contact(firstname,lastname,phone) values('Joao Pedro','Pereira',35 9851 9730);
```

Seu problema está nos `INSERT`'s você está esquecendo de colocar aspas no campo `phone`, veja como você está colocando:

```
"insert into contact(firstname,lastname,phone) values('Joao Pedro','Pereira',35 9851 9730);",
"insert into contact(firstname,lastname,phone) values('Maria Amelia','Rodrigues',45 8814 9292);",
"insert into contact(firstname,lastname,phone) values('Pedro','Silva',15 9102 8922);" };
```

O correto seria:

```
"insert into contact(firstname,lastname,phone) values('Joao Pedro','Pereira','35 9851 9730');",
"insert into contact(firstname,lastname,phone) values('Maria Amelia','Rodrigues','45 8814 9292');",
"insert into contact(firstname,lastname,phone) values('Pedro','Silva','15 9102 8922');" };
```

Comment: Obrigado, o erro foi corrigido. Porém apareceu outro quando fui testar, que apontava um null pointer exception nas linhas 34 e 39 do ContactRegister. Vou editar o código para você poder dar uma olhada e dizer se sabe o que é.

Comment: Paulo, [abri uma Meta Pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1115/201) a respeito desta pergunta aqui, pode dar sua opinião lá?